# validates_uniqueness_of...and unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

What's the proper way to write?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :a, :scope => [:b, :c], :unless => !d.nil?
```

Comment: You can replace `!d.nil?` with `d.present?`. Much easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very simple:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :a, :scope => [:b, :c], :unless => :d
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a `Proc` that returns true or false to the `:if` or `:unless` option:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :a, :scope => [:b, :c], :unless => Proc.new { |obj| !obj.d.nil? }
validates_uniqueness_of :a, :scope => [:b, :c], :if => Proc.new { |obj| obj.d.nil? }
```

(This assumes that `d` is a property or method of your model.)

Of course, this is not a perfect guarantee of uniqueness.  By default there is a race condition that could allow duplicates.  See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001400) for more information.